# Running QAD mfg/pro program using mbpro, do I need mf.p to run in the script?

Tags: progress-4gl

I'm trying to run a QAD mfg/pro (running on Progress 10.1) program using mbpro command. I've provided the database, Propath and other startup parameters to my shell script. When I run the script, mbpro runs the .r program. But issue I'm facing is when my program runs through mbpro, it can't find variables like global_db etc. I get the error in the errorfile.err:

```
Shared variable global_user_lang_dir has not yet been created. (392)
```

When I run the same program from mfg/pro menu, it runs without issue. Which makes me think that the environment is not loaded with all the information. Do I need to run mf.p along with mbpro to load all environment variables? My script file is as follows:

```
exec $DLC/bin/mbpro \
 sports
 -p xxtestprogram.r\
 -d mdy -yy 1990 -Bt 350 -c 30 -D 100 -mmax 3000 -nb 200 -s 3500 \
 > errorfile.err
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to run mf.p at the startup of your session -- probably as more or less the first thing that xxtestprogram.r does.

Depending on the specifics of how you have coded xxtestprogram and what needs to exist before it can even run you might even need to backup a step and create a wrapper that runs mf.p and then runs xxtestprogram.

Comment: The test program is running a query against two tables and projecting couple of columns from the result into a text file. The main issue is I've to use gpalias3.p to switch databases in the test program. Which requires variables like global_db etc to be available.